# How do I implement Vue Router while using Vue UI?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm using Vue UI and I am trying to implement vue routing, but something is wrong. I have two components one called Start and the other called Clubs. For some reason I get two errors in the Vue UI gui stating that it can not find these modules. However, they are currently sat in src > components > . I have look through the documentation and tutorials, some of which have slightly different syntax but no matter what I can't get it to work. Any help welcome.

Currently, mt main.js is as follows;

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import App from './App.vue'

import Start from './Start.vue'
import Clubs from './Clubs.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
    { path: '/', components: Start },
    { path: '/clubs', components: Clubs }
];

const router = new VueRouter ({
     routes: routes
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  routes,
  render: h => h(App)
});
```

Comment: Can you provide some live code (on codesandbox or something) ?

Comment: @BeniaminH Never heard of codesandbox before. Looks very useful https://codesandbox.io/s/o5nrrom079

Comment: There is only HelloWorld component in `components/` directory. No Start nor Clubs.

Comment: @BeniaminH Apologies I missed that bit. They should be there now.

Comment: Now it seems to load components fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/m5p7wk7klx - when you add `components/` to your imports. But now you are getting a different error related with ng-router.

Comment: As @BeniaminH said, your component imports should be `import Start from './components/Start.vue'` and `import Clubs from './components/Clubs.vue'`. Your components are in sub-folder `components` relative to your `main.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Your codes in between lines 10-13 are must be as below, you called with `components` key, it should be `component`

```
const routes = [
  { path: "/", component: Start },
  { path: "/clubs", component: Clubs }
];
```

And you should change `routes` with `router` in line 21

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router, // not 'routes'
  render: h => h(App)
});
```